# placing d3 label at end of arc

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Given the following speed dial, which is constructed using arcs in D3:

```
segmentArc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth).startAngle(arcStartRad + startPadRad).endAngle(arcEndRad - endPadRad);
```

How do I move the labels in each segment so that it appears right justified (at the end of each segment opposed to center)?

[image: d3 arc chart]

the labels are currently added likes this:

```
        chart.append('text')
            .attr('transform', () => {

                var x = Math.round(segmentArc.centroid()[0]);
                var y = Math.round(segmentArc.centroid()[1]);

                return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';

            })
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(sectionLabel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by replicating each segment arc, giving it a transparent fill and making it exactly twice as long. From there it is as simple as working out the centroid for the transparent arc.